# Primary key with hibernate in two tables

Tags: hibernate, primary-key, nhibernate-mapping

I am  trying to learn Hibernate and I have two class related to each other; Person and Address. Person compose Address object and on db Person table has address_id column.

Basically:

1) Table Person has columns: id, name, age, address_id
2) Table Address has columns: id, street, city

What I observe is when I insert a record, it use id=1 for Person table and id=2 for Address table. So it looks like it generates PK from the same sequence. Actually everything is working but why it is like that, why it does not use id=1 in Address table?

Code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {


    public Person(){

    }

    public Person(String name, int age, Adress adress){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    private Adress adress;
}
```

Another class is:

```
@Entity
public class Adress {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;


    public Adress(){

    }

    public Adress(String street, String city){
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }
```

And I am calling save method as :

```
  private static void addPerson(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        Adress adress = new Adress("Wroclawska", "Krakow");
        Person person = new Person("Cemal Inanc", 31, adress);

        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session= sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(person);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            tx.rollback();
            System.out.println("Exeception occured");
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have used the default Generator strategy, So for oracle, it is Sequence.

Internally it will create a sequence in the database and get value from that sequence.

Now you want to get the separate sequence for both of your entity. You need to specify

```
@SequenceGenerator()
```

Changes you have to make in your code:

**For Person Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GeneratorName")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="GeneratorName", sequenceName = "seq1")
    private int id;    
}
```

**For Address Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Adress {

    @Id
    GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GeneratorName")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="GeneratorName", sequenceName = "seq2")
    private int id;
}
```

After applying these changes, You will get both the id's starting from 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses per default the same sequence or table for alle entities if you don't specify the sequence name.

If you want to use sequences and your database supports that you must specify the the generation strategy and the sequence generator.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "sequence-generator"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "sequence-generator",
    sequenceName = "address_sequence"
)
private int id;
```

Read more about this in the official Hibernate documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers